# Convert SQL Query To LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I Know basic LINQ but I have not worked with it in a couple of years. So I've forgotten LINQ. I Can't convert this SQL query to LINQ.

```
   SELECT  
   [CompanyName]
  ,[ContactPerson]
  ,[Address]
  ,[Email]
  ,[InActive]
  ,(Select SUM(isnull(CreditAmount,0) - isnull(DebitAmount,0))  FROM [dbo].[SupplierTransaction] where SupplierId = s.SupplierId)  as Balance FROM [dbo].[Supplier] S
```

[image]

I tried this but its not working

```
from s in Suppliers
select new
{
s.SupplierId,
s.CompanyName,
s.ContactPerson,
s.Address,
s.Email,
s.InActive,
s.BranchId,
s.CreateDate,
s.CreatedBy,
s.UpdateDate,
s.UpdatedBy,
s.PhoneNumber,
Balance = (from v in SupplierTransactions
                          where v.SupplierId ==  s.SupplierId
                          select (v.Sum(v.CreditAmount-v.DebitAmount)))
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show what you tried so far and what doesn't work. Providing the errors, exceptions or unexpected results you get. That way people can help you instead of writing code for you.

Comment: sorry now update my question

Comment: please detail how it is not working

Comment: Please expand on `not working`.

Comment: Balance = (from v in SupplierTransactions
                              where v.SupplierId ==  s.SupplierId
                              select ((v.CreditAmount).Sum()-(v.CreditAmount).Sum()))
         
         }







i tried this. but showing this error " 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'"

Comment: Does it work without Balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it, but it should look something like that :

```
var query = (from s in Suppliers 
             select new 
             {
                 SupplierId = s.SupplierId,
                 CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                 ContactPerson = s.ContactPerson,
                 Address = s.Address,
                 Email = s.Email,
                 InActive = s.InActive,
                 BranchId = s.BranchId,
                 CreateDate = s.CreateDate,
                 CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy,
                 UpdateDate = s.UpdateDate,
                 UpdateBy = s.UpdatedBy,
                 PhoneNumber = s.PhoneNumber,
                 Balance = SupplierTransactions
                          .Where(st => st.SupplierId == s.SupplierId)
                          .Select(st => (st.CreditAmount - st.DebitAmount))
                          .Sum()
             });
```

Comment: Oops. Please, be careful I made a mistake in the where condition. You should replace one st.SupplierId by  s.SupplierID ... I edited my answer !